# What is a more stable way to handle user privileges in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im dealing with a small application with limited users. The specifications are that there two types of users. One is an admin user that should be able post and delete. Whereas the regular user should only be able to read.  I was thinking of doing one of two solutions.

The fist being was to have the same templates for both users and then when an regular user tries to update or delete to throw a notification or warning telling them. I would need to include a User object and I was thinking of doing it at the router level. So the router would check whether the request is coming from an admin or a regular user.

The second solution would be to include two templates, one for regular users and another for admin. Im leaning towards the first solution as that way I dont have the redundancy in the app. It also abstracts away most of the logic to a higher level. Interested in input though.

Comment: Whatever route you choose to take, just remember that anyone who tries hard enough to bypass your *client* security, can probably do so. Make sure you have some kind of permissions check on the backend as well.

Comment: This is my opinion and suggestion: do not provide unusable UI components. It will annoy people to have buttons on the UI that they can't use. Also, checking user authorization at the router level is superfluous and easily bypassed as tymeJV pointed out. So definitely go with the two-templates path by using the router to select between views. Authorization checks should be on the back-end.

Comment: Unusable features are no deal if using ng-hide. Ofc that doesn't prevent anyone from bypassing, but it should be enouhg for the frontend.

Comment: You want to keep your code dry (i.e. if most of the code is the same, don't repeat it in two places). If you are able to, just abstract out the parts that are different for the different user types.

Comment: Yea makes sense just to embed it in the template with ng-view, the domain isnt complex and its pretty static.